# Fast hash for 2 coordinates where order doesn't matter?

Tags: python, hash, hashmap, key, hashcode

Is there a formula that is a one way hash for 2 coordinates (a, b) and (c, d) to one integer where a, b, c, and d are positive? Order **doesn't** matter here, so the formula should give the same results when given `(a, b), (c, d)` and `(c, d), (a, b)`. The order of the actual numbers in each coordinate point matter (`(a, b)` is not the same as `(b, a)`). Speed is the key here, the formula should be fast and have O(1) complexity.

Note - what I'm doing right now is sorting the two coordinates using Python's building in sort, and then using them as keys in Python's built-in dictionary (so, built-in hashing). I need a faster way of doing this so that I can hash the two coordinates to an integer myself.

Comment: have you a max value for your coordinates?

Comment: No, there is not limit given on either the x or y values.

Comment: any requirement about collisions? and maybe you could sort them manually instead of using python sort which has some overhead for small lists like yours.

Comment: I would prefer not to have collision resolution just because of the extra time that would take. However, I will sort them manually - that makes sense. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Are the coordinates integers?

Comment: Yes all coordinates are positive integers.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [hash()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash) of a [frozenset](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-frozenset) for this.

```
>>> hash(frozenset([(10, 20), (11, 22)]))
1735850283064117985
>>> hash(frozenset([(11, 22), (10, 20)]))
1735850283064117985
```

Frozensets were specifically designed for this kind of use case (i.e. frozensets are intrinsically unordered collections that are immutable and hashable).

Hope this answer takes your right to what you needed :-)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about frozen sets. Thanks!